# 4020 error on Opencart 2.0.2.0 with Sagepay Server. Added valid IP in SagePay control panel. Any ideas?

Tags: opayo

I'm currently upgrading the website for a client so that we can use the new v3.0 protocol.

We are using Opencart 2.0.2.0. We are using the Sagepay Server extension that comes as standard with opencart.

We are using Sagepay Server as a replacement for the form method - as advised here - http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=185&t=133604

The upgraded server is sitting on a sub-domain whilst I test. I've added the server IP to the valid IP within the sagepay account. However when I test. I still get a 4020 error.

The sub-domain I'm using is http://jab.juice-e.co.uk

The IP i've added to the SagePay control panel is 079.170.044.142 and subnet 255.255.255.255.

Any ideas why this may not be working?

Answer (score 0):

When ever I've seen these in the past, it means you still don't have the correct IP in My Sage Pay. Few things to try:

1. Try widening the subnet to 255.255.255.000 in case your actual IP is somewhere within the range (but not exactly what you have).
2. Get the TransactionID (from the Invalid Transactions page in My Sage Pay), call Sage Pay support, give them the ID and they can check the transaction logs for the originating IP
3. From the server, look at whatismyip.com and get the ip as it appears externally, and add this to MSP